# Reading from a file without skipping whitespaces

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

I'm trying to make a code which would change one given word from a file, and change it into another one. The program works in a way that it copies word by word, if it's normal word it just writes it into the output file, and if it's the one i need to change it writes the one i need to change to. However, I've enountered a problem. Program is not putting whitespaces where they are in the input file. I don't know the solution to this problem, and I have no idea if I can use `noskipws` since I wouldn't know where the file ends.

Please keep in mind I'm a complete newbie and I have no idea how things work. I don't know if the tags are visible enough, so I will mention again that I use C++

Comment: See the input modifier [`noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws).

Comment: Obviously, you *do* know when you have reached end of file: the attempt to read another character or word fails.

Comment: The 'eof()' isn't working when I use 'noskipws'. But I guess I shouldn't be using that to check if the file have ended

Comment: `eof()` isn't the way to determine the end of file anyway: you check the stream state, i.e., you'd try to read and then check the stream's state, e.g., by converting it to a Boolean value, e.g., `while (stream >> value) { ... }`. Of course, you'll need to read the space characters between words when `std::ios_base::noskipws` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each reading of word is ended with either a whitespace or end of file, you could simply check whether the thing which stop your reading is end of file, or otherwise a whitespace:

```
if ( reached the end of file ) {
  // What I have encountered is end of file 
  // My job is done
} else {
  // What I have encountered is a whitespace
  // I need to output a whitespace and back to work
}
```

And the problem here is how to check the eof(end of file).
Since you are using ifstream, things will be quite simple.
When a ifstream reach the end of file (all the meaningful data have been read), the ifstream::eof() function will return true.
Let's assume the ifstream instance that you have is called input.

```
if ( input.eof() == true ) {
  // What I have encountered is end of file
  // My job is done
} else {
  // What I have encountered is a whitespace
  // I need to output a whitespace and back to work
}
```

PS : ifstream::good() will return false when it reaches the eof or an error occurs. Checking whether input.good() == false instead can be a better choice here.

Comment: Recommend testing against `if (!input)` rather than `if ( input.eof() == true )` because a lot more can go wrong in a stream than merely end of file. Just testing for EOF allows the code to go into an infinite loop of bad reads.

Comment: How would I know if it's whitespace or newline?

Comment: Checking input is better than eof(), and the same as good(). Though using an ifstream as condition may be confusing for beginner.

Comment: My suggestion is : read a line each time, and use a istringstream to break down the line into words. By the way, formatting an ill formed article can be very diffcult.

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise you not to read and write in the same file (at least not during reading) because it will make your program much more difficult to write/read.

Second if you want to read all whitespaces easiest is to read whole line with getline().

Program that you can use for modifying words from one file to another could look something like following:

```
void read_file()
{
    ifstream file_read;
    ofstream file_write;
    // File from which you read some text.
    file_read.open ("read.txt");
    // File in which you will save modified text.
    file_write.open ("write.txt");

    string line;
    // Word that you look for to modify.       
    string word_to_modify = "something";
    string word_new = "something_new";

    // You need to look in every line from input file. 
    // getLine() goes from beginning of the file to the end.
    while ( getline (file_read,line) ) {
        unsigned index = line.find(word_to_modify);
        // If there are one or more occurrence of target word.
        while (index < line.length()) {
            line.replace(index, word_to_modify.length(), word_new);
            index = line.find(word_to_modify, index + word_new.length());
        }

        cout << line << '\n';
        file_write << line + '\n';
    }


    file_read.close();
    file_write.close();
}
```